# mat-tab - click triggers ripple effect but not tab change

Tags: angular, electron, mat-tab

In my angular-electron app I use mat-tab-group, in every tab i load the same instance of a component.

I have two ways to create new Tabs:
- one by clicking a button in the component which holds the mat-tab-group
- the second one is triggered via an IPC message.

Both ways call the same function, where I push a new object to an array, the tabs are created via *ngFor on this array.

The effect:

While the "second" tab created by the clicked button behaves normally, the one triggered via IPC ("third") does not:

The ripple effect is shown right on the click on the "third"-tab, but the click event on the tab (selectedTabChange) is only triggered when i click a second time somewhere in the window. Also, the content of the tab (wrapped in an ng-template) is changed only after the second click.

Both, the component which holds the tabs as well as the one which is instantiated in every tab, use push strategy in change detection.

I am pretty sure that this has something to do with ngZones, but I am not sure how I could solve this problem. Thanks for any help!

Animated Gif here:

[switching Tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UH464.gif)

Code HTML:

```
<mat-icon  (click)="MakeTabActive()">build</mat-icon>

<mat-tab-group mat-align-tabs="start" [selectedIndex]="selectedTab" (selectedTabChange)="RegisterTabChange($event)">
                <mat-tab *ngFor="let item of openWfTabs">
                  <ng-template mat-tab-label>
                      {{item.title}}
                    <mat-icon class="example-tab-icon" (click)="removeTabHandler(item.uid)">close</mat-icon>
                  </ng-template>
                  {{item.uid}}
                  <app-wf-tabcontent [wfContentElementUID]=item.uid>
                  </app-wf-tabcontent>
                </mat-tab>
              </mat-tab-group>
```

Code TS:

```
this._electronService.ipcRenderer.on('to-all', (event, arg) => {

  this.MakeTabActive();

});


MakeTabActive(newTab?:any) {
 if (!newTab) {
  newTab = new WfTab();
 }

 if (!this.openWfTabs.includes(newTab)) {
      this.openWfDocumentElements.push(newTab);
 }

    for (let i:number = 0; i<this.openWfTabs.length;i++) {
      if (this.openWfTabs[i].uid == newTab.uid) {
        this.selectedTab = i;
      }
    }
    this.ref.detectChanges();
  }
```

Comment: Would you mind showing some code, specifically what happens on your IPC trigger? Normally I would usually just store selectedIndex in a variable and update that variable accordingly as in the example here https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/examples "Tab group with dynamically changing tabs"

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added code to my question and hope this clarifies it. I followed the example you linked to pretty closely...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, that was way easier than I thought:

Turns out that because of the subscription to the Electron Service, the code ran outside the NgZone and it stayed there.

I found out because I inserted this in the called function:
    console.log(NgZone.isInAngularZone());

The same function returned one time true, one time false on this, depending on how I called it.

The solution was really straightforward:

In the subscription to the electron service, I now call the createTab function like this:
    this.ngZone.run(() => this.createNewTab());